# Importing CSV file that is separated by columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to import a CSV file using pandas, this is usually not a problem, but now this file is not separated by commas, but each field is in a different column, it looks like:

```
2020-01-01;2020-01-01 00:00:00.0;2020-01-01 00:05:00.0;SE3;1205.864
2020-01-01;2020-01-01 00:05:00.0;2020-01-01 00:10:00.0;SE3;1211.574
2020-01-01;2020-01-01 00:10:00.0;2020-01-01 00:15:00.0;SE3;1217.963
2020-01-01;2020-01-01 00:15:00.0;2020-01-01 00:20:00.0;SE3;1224.422
```

I first tried this approach

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\simon\Desktop\Vindkraftsprognos∩2020 elområde 5 min.csv')
```

Which can create a DataFrame, but all the data is in a single column.

I also tried to change the extension of the file to "xlsx" and use this code:

```
svk_df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\simon\Desktop\Vindkraftsprognos∩2020 elområde 5 min.xlsx")
```

Which gives me an Error `ValueError: Worksheet index 0 is invalid, 0 worksheets found`.

Any help on how to solve this would be appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: Changed the picture for text instead. Also tried the solution from the answer:

```
 result = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\simon\Desktop\Vindkraftsprognos∩2020 elområde 5 min.csv', sep='\s+',header=None)
```

Which gives me three columns, out of the five from the excel-file.

```
                       0                      1                        2
0  2020-01-01;2020-01-01  00:00:00.0;2020-01-01  00:05:00.0;SE3;1205.864
1  2020-01-01;2020-01-01  00:05:00.0;2020-01-01  00:10:00.0;SE3;1211.574
2  2020-01-01;2020-01-01  00:10:00.0;2020-01-01  00:15:00.0;SE3;1217.963
3  2020-01-01;2020-01-01  00:15:00.0;2020-01-01  00:20:00.0;SE3;1224.422
4  2020-01-01;2020-01-01  00:20:00.0;2020-01-01   00:25:00.0;SE3;1230.81
```

Comment: Your picture doesn't look like a .csv file (might be an excel file). What does your csv look like? It would also be much more helpful if you post it as text, not as an image.

Comment: read_csv has a argumenet called separator try that `sep='|'`. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: To determine the separator, look at the csv in a text editor (such as notepad++ on Windows), not Excel. Then adjust the `read_csv` keywords accordingly. `sep=";"` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Didn't know this trick on how to find the separator. I assumed that only the standard csv-file, with everything in one column and separated by comma, had a separator. I checked in notepad and updated  the separator accordingly (`sep=";"`) and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This should works fine.
you can try change `sep="|"` also as commented.

note: it is better to use realtive path with pandas consider putting dataset in same folder of your script.

```
 result = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\simon\Desktop\Vindkraftsprognos∩2020 elområde 5 min.csv', sep=';',header=None)
```

Comment: "*it is better to use realtive path with pandas*" - why's that ?

Comment: Thank you. This code creates a df with three columns, and not five as in the excel-file. I edited the question to include a better picture of the excel file and also the result from your code. (note that the first column on the picture is right aligned)

Comment: @Simon you would need to change sep=;   based on the new update in question

Comment: @FObersteiner as pandas start looking for dataset from current directory